# Is it more efficient to store vector size into an int variable when using it multiple times?

Tags: c++

So if we have the code below:

```
vector<string> vec1;
//initialize vec1 to contain thousands of strings

for (int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++) {
    //.....
}

for (int j = 0; j < vec1.size(); j++){
   //......
}
```

Would it be faster to declare an int vec_size = vec1.size() and use it like so:

```
int vec_size = vec1.size();

for (int i = 0; i < vec_size; i++) {
        //.....
    }

for (int j = 0; j < vec_size; i++) {
        //.....
    }
```

and if so, why?

Comment: The compiler would have already done it in this case (using a temporary variable).

Comment: Why didn't you measure?

Comment: By the way, questions like this are easy to verify by checking the assembly output of your compiler.

Comment: It's an optimization *thingy*.  If a value is used many times but only set or calculated once, it should go into a constant variable.  There is an overhead associated with function calls.  But, as others have said, this maybe moot depending on your compiler optimization settings and capabilities.  THE TRUTH IS OUT THERE, in the assembly language listing. :-)

Comment: If you are able to use a C++11 compiler, use the range `for` loop and forget about this issue altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on compiler optimization settings.  At some optimization settings, the compiler may realize that the string is not changing and thus only call the function once.

In the `for` loop, the expression `j < vec1.size()` is called for each iteration.  If the vector size doesn't change in the loop, that is a bunch of wasted function calls.  Calling it once and assigning to a variable reduces the execution to one call of `std::vector::size()`.

By the way, the `size()` method returns `size_t`, which is usually compatible with `unsigned int`. (vectors can't have a negative size).

So your loop should be:

```
const size_t vec_size = vec1.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec_size; ++i)
{
  //...
}
```

The declaration of the vector size variable as a constant allows the compiler to perform more optimizations; your telling the compiler that the variable won't change its value.

Comment: Hmm, yes, +1 for noticing the signed variable. I've seen a compiler optimization defeated by exactly this -- its range analysis couldn't prove that the variable was always positive, so it was unable to apply an optimization to the loop. Changing the loop index to `unsigned` yielded the expected optimized code. (This was a custom embedded C compiler, mind, not one of the well-known C++ compilers. Still.)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes. If compiler optimizations are off (e.g. for a debug build), then the method calls might not even be inlined, and it could make a difference.

C++ compilers are very good at optimization, though -- normally the compiler will first inline the method calls, and depending on the contents of the loop, it will see that the vector doesn't change within it and allocate a register for the value instead of reading it each time from the object (again, depending on the loop body -- in a complex loop, dedicating a register to this doesn't make sense since it leaves one less register for all the other work to use, so it won't be done). This boils down to exactly the same thing as if you hoisted it yourself.

In practice -- don't hoist it manually. It hurts the readability of your code, and doesn't improve the speed except when optimizations are off, in which case there are much bigger inefficiencies anyway.